# DB2 / SQL:retrieve the list of IDs modified or inserted

Tags: sql, db2-400

Question on DB2 / 400 SQL (and on SQL in general): is there a way to retrieve the list of IDs modified or inserted following an "update" or "insert" request without going through the heavy mechanics logging ?

Thank you in advance for your ideas, or your opinions on the issue.

Thank's

Comment: What do you mean by "ID"? Do you mean a column in the table labeled "ID" or do you mean the relative record number of the row?

Comment: [This page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafysfins.htm) may be helpful to you regarding INSERTs. I don't have any suggestions for UPDATEs.

Comment: Yes, i want to retrieve the list of identity values in case of "insert" or "update" SQL instruction . But i think there is no way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a unique ID for every row, you could just create a temporary data set of the IDs and then update/insert the data.

For insert, the other answer will work.

For update, you could do the following.

```
Declare global temporary table updatedID
( <ID NAME> <ID TYPE> );
Insert into session.updatedID
Select <ID> from <TABLE> where <CONDITIONAL CLAUSE>
;
Update <TABLE> set <SET STATMENTS> where <ID> in (Select <ID NAME> from session.updatedID)
;
--Optional
Drop table updateID;
```

It is working a little backwards but the easiest way to avoid having to deal with the journals and avoids iterating over the file record by record to update (using a FOR loop).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment...for an insert, use the `SELECT <..> FROM FINAL TABLE` version of the insert

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPSAMP 
    (EMPNO     INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
     NAME      CHAR(30),
     SALARY    DECIMAL(10,2),
     DEPTNO    SMALLINT,
     LEVEL     CHAR(30),
     HIRETYPE  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'New Employee',
     HIREDATE  DATE NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT)


SELECT EMPNO, HIRETYPE, HIREDATE
  FROM FINAL TABLE ( INSERT INTO EMPSAMP (NAME, SALARY, DEPTNO, LEVEL)
                                 VALUES('Mary Smith', 35000.00, 11, 'Associate'))
```

If there are after insert triggers or referential constraints that alter the inserted data, using `FINAL TABLE` as above will result in an error.  You can use `NEW TABLE` instead.  However, the results from `NEW TABLE` are from before after triggers and referential constraints.  So the data that ends up in the table could be different that what is returned.

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent  [*data-change-table-reference*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafztabref.htm) for `UPDATE` statements..

What's your use case on the update?